# How to filter a query in ngMaterial md-autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I need to filter the results in the client side, i mean, without passing an ajax parameter. But I can't figure this out.
Here is my js:

```
    angular.module('myapp', ['ngMaterial']).controller("autocompleteController", function ($http) {this.querySearch = function (query) {
            return $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
                .then(function (response) {
 //wild black magic stuff needed here
                    return response.data;
                })
        }
    });
```

and my html:

```
<md-autocomplete flex
                         md-select-on-match="true"
                         md-autofocus="true"
                         md-autoselect="true"
                         md-selected-item="item.name"
                         md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
                         md-search-text-change="ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
                         md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
                         md-item-text="item.name"
                         md-delay="300"
                         md-floating-label="Nome do Paciente">
            <div layout="row" class="item" layout-align="start center">
                <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </md-autocomplete>
```

And plunker if needed https://embed.plnkr.co/Kov5pgwqkv1ZyCCOIsCX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a filter like this inside the promise to filter the data by name

```
.then(function(response) {
    var res = response.data.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) != -1;
    });
    return res;
})
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xdJtLh8gBhK7ksTy3mMk?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the job! p.s: I upvoted you but it said that won't show it public because i'm newbie